# Select fields in JSON output - string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I have searched for the past hour but I can't find an answer.

Basically, I am using this code to extract tweets from a list of tweets using the twitter API:

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError
import os
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

tweets = t.lists.statuses(list_id=123456, count=5, include_rts=2) #Retrieve 5 most recent tweets

print json.dumps(tweets, indent=4) #Prints human readable json output
```

This is the output:

```
[
    {
        "contributors": null, 
        "truncated": false, 
        "text": "Por isso que eu te amo @Namorou \ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02 http://t.co/jbBvyvDQig", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "id": 528407407794589696, 
        "favorite_count": 20, 
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [], 
            "user_mentions": [
                {
                    "id": 267890604, 
                    "indices": [
                        23, 
                        31
                    ], 
                    "id_str": "267890604", 
                    "screen_name": "Namorou", 
                    "name": "Namorou"
                }
            ], 
            "hashtags": [], 
            "urls": [], 
            "media": [
                {
                    "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/drogalizado/status/528407407794589696/photo/1", 
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/jbBvyvDQig", 
                    "url": "http://t.co/jbBvyvDQig", 
                    "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1VHvE3IMAEtczX.jpg", 
                    "id_str": "528407405370290177", 
                    "sizes": {
                        "large": {
                            "h": 800, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 480
                        }, 
                        "small": {
                            "h": 566, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 340
                        }, 
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 800, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 480
                        }, 
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150, 
                            "resize": "crop", 
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    }, 
                    "indices": [
                        42, 
                        64
                    ], 
                    "type": "photo", 
                    "id": 528407405370290177, 
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1VHvE3IMAEtczX.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "id_str": "528407407794589696", 
        "retweet_count": 3, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false, 
            "profile_use_background_image": true, 
            "profile_text_color": "666666", 
            "default_profile_image": false, 
            "id": 193021875, 
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "verified": false, 
            "profile_location": null, 
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429", 
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
                            "indices": [
                                0, 
                                22
                            ], 
                            "expanded_url": "http://instagram.com/oficialdrogalizado", 
                            "display_url": "instagram.com/oficialdrogali\u2026"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }, 
            "followers_count": 532405, 
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "id_str": "193021875", 
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "listed_count": 313, 
            "is_translation_enabled": false, 
            "utc_offset": -7200, 
            "statuses_count": 21797, 
            "description": "\u2709 PUBLICIDADE: drogalizadopublicidades@outlook.com", 
            "friends_count": 85, 
            "location": "Porto Alegre - RS", 
            "profile_link_color": "000000", 
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "following": false, 
            "geo_enabled": false, 
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/193021875/1414118102", 
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "name": "drogado", 
            "lang": "pt", 
            "profile_background_tile": false, 
            "favourites_count": 216, 
            "screen_name": "drogalizado", 
            "notifications": false, 
            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
            "created_at": "Mon Sep 20 19:40:24 +0000 2010", 
            "contributors_enabled": false, 
            "time_zone": "Brasilia", 
            "protected": false, 
            "default_profile": false, 
            "is_translator": false
        }, 
        "geo": null, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "possibly_sensitive": false, 
        "lang": "pt", 
        "created_at": "Sat Nov 01 04:45:18 +0000 2014", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "place": null, 
        "extended_entities": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/drogalizado/status/528407407794589696/photo/1", 
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/jbBvyvDQig", 
                    "url": "http://t.co/jbBvyvDQig", 
                    "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1VHvE3IMAEtczX.jpg", 
                    "id_str": "528407405370290177", 
                    "sizes": {
                        "large": {
                            "h": 800, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 480
                        }, 
                        "small": {
                            "h": 566, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 340
                        }, 
                        "medium": {
                            "h": 800, 
                            "resize": "fit", 
                            "w": 480
                        }, 
                        "thumb": {
                            "h": 150, 
                            "resize": "crop", 
                            "w": 150
                        }
                    }, 
                    "indices": [
                        42, 
                        64
                    ], 
                    "type": "photo", 
                    "id": 528407405370290177, 
                    "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1VHvE3IMAEtczX.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "contributors": null, 
        "truncated": false, 
        "text": "vai dormir juan uehuehueh @Namorou", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 528405300832116736, 
        "id": 528405454108786688, 
        "favorite_count": 7, 
        "source": "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>", 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [], 
            "user_mentions": [
                {
                    "id": 267890604, 
                    "indices": [
                        26, 
                        34
                    ], 
                    "id_str": "267890604", 
                    "screen_name": "Namorou", 
                    "name": "Namorou"
                }
            ], 
            "hashtags": [], 
            "urls": []
        }, 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Namorou", 
        "id_str": "528405454108786688", 
        "retweet_count": 0, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": 267890604, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false, 
            "profile_use_background_image": true, 
            "profile_text_color": "666666", 
            "default_profile_image": false, 
            "id": 193021875, 
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "verified": false, 
            "profile_location": null, 
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429", 
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
                            "indices": [
                                0, 
                                22
                            ], 
                            "expanded_url": "http://instagram.com/oficialdrogalizado", 
                            "display_url": "instagram.com/oficialdrogali\u2026"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }, 
            "followers_count": 532405, 
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "id_str": "193021875", 
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "listed_count": 313, 
            "is_translation_enabled": false, 
            "utc_offset": -7200, 
            "statuses_count": 21797, 
            "description": "\u2709 PUBLICIDADE: drogalizadopublicidades@outlook.com", 
            "friends_count": 85, 
            "location": "Porto Alegre - RS", 
            "profile_link_color": "000000", 
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "following": false, 
            "geo_enabled": false, 
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/193021875/1414118102", 
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "name": "drogado", 
            "lang": "pt", 
            "profile_background_tile": false, 
            "favourites_count": 216, 
            "screen_name": "drogalizado", 
            "notifications": false, 
            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
            "created_at": "Mon Sep 20 19:40:24 +0000 2010", 
            "contributors_enabled": false, 
            "time_zone": "Brasilia", 
            "protected": false, 
            "default_profile": false, 
            "is_translator": false
        }, 
        "geo": null, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "267890604", 
        "lang": "in", 
        "created_at": "Sat Nov 01 04:37:32 +0000 2014", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "528405300832116736", 
        "place": null
    }, 
    {
        "contributors": null, 
        "truncated": false, 
        "text": "mulher nenhuma presta, tudo puta.. vo vira gay.", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "id": 528404407621517312, 
        "favorite_count": 62, 
        "source": "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>", 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [], 
            "user_mentions": [], 
            "hashtags": [], 
            "urls": []
        }, 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "id_str": "528404407621517312", 
        "retweet_count": 17, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false, 
            "profile_use_background_image": true, 
            "profile_text_color": "666666", 
            "default_profile_image": false, 
            "id": 193021875, 
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "verified": false, 
            "profile_location": null, 
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429", 
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
                            "indices": [
                                0, 
                                22
                            ], 
                            "expanded_url": "http://instagram.com/oficialdrogalizado", 
                            "display_url": "instagram.com/oficialdrogali\u2026"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }, 
            "followers_count": 532405, 
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "id_str": "193021875", 
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "listed_count": 313, 
            "is_translation_enabled": false, 
            "utc_offset": -7200, 
            "statuses_count": 21797, 
            "description": "\u2709 PUBLICIDADE: drogalizadopublicidades@outlook.com", 
            "friends_count": 85, 
            "location": "Porto Alegre - RS", 
            "profile_link_color": "000000", 
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "following": false, 
            "geo_enabled": false, 
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/193021875/1414118102", 
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "name": "drogado", 
            "lang": "pt", 
            "profile_background_tile": false, 
            "favourites_count": 216, 
            "screen_name": "drogalizado", 
            "notifications": false, 
            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
            "created_at": "Mon Sep 20 19:40:24 +0000 2010", 
            "contributors_enabled": false, 
            "time_zone": "Brasilia", 
            "protected": false, 
            "default_profile": false, 
            "is_translator": false
        }, 
        "geo": null, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "lang": "pt", 
        "created_at": "Sat Nov 01 04:33:22 +0000 2014", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "place": null
    }, 
    {
        "contributors": null, 
        "truncated": false, 
        "text": "Linkin Park - Given Up \u2764\ufe0f", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "id": 528401445595652096, 
        "favorite_count": 71, 
        "source": "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>", 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [], 
            "user_mentions": [], 
            "hashtags": [], 
            "urls": []
        }, 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "id_str": "528401445595652096", 
        "retweet_count": 34, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false, 
            "profile_use_background_image": true, 
            "profile_text_color": "666666", 
            "default_profile_image": false, 
            "id": 193021875, 
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "verified": false, 
            "profile_location": null, 
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429", 
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
                            "indices": [
                                0, 
                                22
                            ], 
                            "expanded_url": "http://instagram.com/oficialdrogalizado", 
                            "display_url": "instagram.com/oficialdrogali\u2026"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }, 
            "followers_count": 532405, 
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "id_str": "193021875", 
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF", 
            "listed_count": 313, 
            "is_translation_enabled": false, 
            "utc_offset": -7200, 
            "statuses_count": 21797, 
            "description": "\u2709 PUBLICIDADE: drogalizadopublicidades@outlook.com", 
            "friends_count": 85, 
            "location": "Porto Alegre - RS", 
            "profile_link_color": "000000", 
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491755793402699776/hVyYJkdQ_normal.png", 
            "following": false, 
            "geo_enabled": false, 
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/193021875/1414118102", 
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/524633821375782913/DylvNU_t.png", 
            "name": "drogado", 
            "lang": "pt", 
            "profile_background_tile": false, 
            "favourites_count": 216, 
            "screen_name": "drogalizado", 
            "notifications": false, 
            "url": "http://t.co/yfxyixAeU5", 
            "created_at": "Mon Sep 20 19:40:24 +0000 2010", 
            "contributors_enabled": false, 
            "time_zone": "Brasilia", 
            "protected": false, 
            "default_profile": false, 
            "is_translator": false
        }, 
        "geo": null, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "lang": "en", 
        "created_at": "Sat Nov 01 04:21:36 +0000 2014", 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "place": null
    }
]
```

I  want to select the `id_str` and `retweet_count` of **all the 5 tweets** in the output. `print(myjson[0]['text'])` returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`.

How can I select fields from this type of json structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `tweets` is a Python list, so tweets[0] is the first one.  Each tweet in the list is a Python dict, so you can say tweets[0]['contributors'] to get the first dict's 'contributors' value (in this case it will by Python None).

You can browse down into other parts of the structure similarly.  This should get you the first tweet's first user mention's 'id_str' value:

```
tweets[0]['entities']['user_mentions'][0]['id_str']
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your answer, but `IndexError: list index out of range` returned `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Vince, the above code snippet won't work when a tweet has no user_mentions at all, as a couple in your above sample do.  You need to work out the details yourself here (assuming this is homework).

Comment: I see, I got it using `print tweets[0]['retweet_count']`, and if I change `[0]` I can't get the retweet_count of the other tweets. Thanks!

Comment: I understood how to go even further, for example `print tweets[0]['user']['entities']['url']['urls'][0]['url']`. Thanks again!